# Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC

Tags: tlmgr, perl

When invoking `tlgmr`, especially in the course of a distribution upgrade, it fails very early with a PERL error `Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC` followed by a list for `@INC` in the following form : `@INC contains: /2020/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /2020/tlpkg` etc.

Setting the `PERL5LIB` to the appropriate folder allows to get a little further but things still fail with

`kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /2020/bin/x86_64-linux` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when one invokes `tlmgr` by specifying a relative path to it that does not begin with `./`, eg. `user@machine:/opt/texlive$ 2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self --all`.

For some (PERL-related ?) reason, this makes tlmgr search for things under `/2020/`.

Use `user@machine:/opt/texlive$ ./2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self --all` instead.

Comment: I get this error with an absolute path: `alias tlmgr='/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl --usermode'
`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Arch Wiki of TeX Live](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#tlmgr),  tlmgr script in TEXMFDIST is broken.
The method to fix is to edit `TEXMFDIST/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl` and replace `$Master = "$Master/../..";` with `$Master = "${Master}/../../..";`.
Or for Arch-based Linux distro user, use [tllocalmgr](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tllocalmgr-git/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the fish shell,but i can't config PATH correctly
but to config `tlmgr`, now i try this solution:

- linux can't found tmlgr:

```
# try to search it in this directory
# /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/
# /opt/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/
# ...
```

- tmlgr cant found Directory: TeXLIVE?
  Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC

```bash
$ /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/
|-- TeXLive
|   |-- TLConfFile.pm
|   |-- TLUtils.pm
....
|-- tlmgr.pl
|-- tlmgrgui.pl
```

- if you not have all `*.pm` needed by `tlmgr`, you can download manual from google , like me , i use `wget http://tug.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm -O /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/TeXLive`
- if `tlmgr` can't found this dir `TeXLive`:
  you must use global var in .bashrc.. but i cant use it in `fishshell` at now, so i make `link` to known `path` by `tlmgr`, from my origin path to /texmf-dist, or in ~/perl...

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/texmf-dist/ /
```

- if you need this file `/tlpkg/installer/config.guess` download from `github` and put it in `tlpkg/installer/`
- sometime you need to use `tlmgr` in usermod:

```bash
$ alias tlmgr='/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl --usermode'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running **tlmgr** through [TinyTex](https://yihui.org/tinytex/) in an [Alpine Docker](https://hub.docker.com/layers/alpine/library/alpine/3.15/images/sha256-8483ecd016885d8dba70426fda133c30466f661bb041490d525658f1aac73822?context=explore) container. To solve this problem I had to do the following:

```
RUN [ "apk", "add", "--no-cache", \
  "texlive", \
  "texlive-xetex", \
  "texmf-dist-latexextra", \
  "texlive-luatex" \
]

RUN [ "R", "-e", "options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE); tinytex::install_tinytex()" ]
RUN [ "ln", "-s", "/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux", "/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linuxmusl" ]
RUN [ "R", "-e", "options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE); tinytex::install_tinytex()" ]

ENV PATH=${PATH}:/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/
```

The first install attempt is to create the needed folders and structures, the second one is to really install it after the symbolic link is created to account for a path configuration issue. This is due to the installer looking for an **'x86_64-linuxmusl'** folder that doesn't exist; the equivalent directory is called **'x86_64-linux'**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the problem is related to Perl. TeXLive expects certain Perl libraries to be present in the system. After reinstallation of Perl, the libraries are lost. I had to reinstall TeXLive (via Homebrew) and the problem disappeared.