# After update, tlmgr can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm

Tags: linux, tlmgr, update, texlive-2024

After updating texlive from 2023 to 2024 on Linux Mint, tlmgr seems to have been broken. When I run `tlmgr update --self` I get the error "Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC".

Output from `perl -e 'print join("\n", @INC)'` includes the path `/usr/local/texlive/2024/tlpkg`

Checking for the missing file using `find /usr/local/texlive/2024 -name TLConfig.pm` shows that the missing file is where it should be, in `/usr/local/texlive/2024/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLConfig.pm`.

The PERL5LIB environment variable is set to `/usr/local/texlive/2024/tlpkg`

Based on a suggestion from a previous post, I also edited `TEXMFDIST/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl` and replaced `$Master = "$Master/../..";` with `$Master = "${Master}/../../..";`, but that didn't have any apparent effect. So I changed it back to its original state.

I have reinstalled texlive (twice) and rebooted.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: `... in a previous post`: it's a big site :(. How did you install TeX Live exactly? Did you use the upstream installer or Linux Mint's package manager? I'm assuming you installed upstream for 2024, but what about 2023? Honestly, I don't think I've ever done anything to get `perl` to recognise the TL directories.  Looking at the scripts, I don't think you need to modify `@INC` as the scripts do it themselves. `tlmgr` finds the paths and then arranges the directory order as necessary. Try undoing all the changes and unsetting `PERL5LIB`. The `perl -e` command returns nothing for me.

Comment: I installed both the 2023 and 2024 versions of TeX Live from the TUG website (https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) using the tl;dr Unix(ish) directions. The "previous post" I mentioned was from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539545/cant-locate-texlive-tlconfig-pm-in-inc/598925#598925. I might just have to try a purge and reinstall.

Comment: That post refers to https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#tlmgr. That has nothing to do with `tlmgr` installed from upstream. It applies only to a non-current `tlmgr` installed as part of an Arch package which is no longer even current. Editing `tlmgr` as instructed there is not only unlikely to help. It is almost guaranteed to break things. Are you certain you reverted the changes you made correctly? You shouldn't need to touch `tlmgr`. Nor should you need to do anything particular to get `perl` to find things.

Comment: Is that the complete output from `tlmgr update --all`? There really ought to be a verbose or debug option, but I can't find one .... If you switch back to 2023, does tlmgr work as expected? (Or course it won't update anything, but does it tell you why not as usual?)

Comment: The complete output of `tlmgr update --all` is `Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TeXLive::TLConfig module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/bin/../../texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /usr/local/bin/../../tlpkg /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34 /usr/share/perl/5.34 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/local/bin/tlmgr line 92.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/tlmgr line 92.`

Comment: "Are you certain you reverted the changes you made correctly?" Short answer: No.  The errors I was correcting began immediately after the update, starting with tlmgr trying to access the 2023 version after the 2024 version was installed. It went downhill from there. My PATH was adjusted in my .zshrc file to point to the 2024 installation, but `echo $PATH` showed both the 2024 (at the beginning) and the 2023 version (at the end). That's where I entered the rabbit hole.

Comment: If you'd logged out and back in before going down the rabbit hole, that probably would have been good. But hindsight is always 20:20. If you've only altered `tlmgr`, you should be able to just reinstall that without starting over from scratch. See https://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html > 'Disaster recovery'. That should get `tlmgr` back into a usable state without downloading the whole of TL again.

Comment: @cfr: This seems to have been the answer the OP was looking for. Please convert a summary into an answer, or close otherwise.

Comment: @Werner I don't see any evidence the OP has even read it, but OK.

Comment: I read it when it was originally posted. I didn't respond because I've been admonished on this site previously for thanking people for providing correct answers. Unfortunately, I don't have adequate credentials to mark the answer as correct (although I flagged it and asked mods to mark it as such). Assuming this response will be as ephemeral as my previous ones, let me say thank you--this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you install upstream's TeX Live on Linux (as opposed to using your Linux distro's packages) and you use the suggested configuration, you will typically need to log out and back in to ensure `PATH` is set appropriately for all shells and programmes.

If you somehow break `tlmgr`, however, you can just reinstall that without reinstalling everything from scratch. See tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html > 'Disaster recovery'. That should get tlmgr back into a usable state without downloading the whole of TL again.

### Note 1

Don't edit scripts provided by TeX Live unless you are confident the changes apply to your situation. Even then, make a copy of the original in case you need to reverse them.

Unless you have a very non-standard configuration, you should not need to do anything to get `perl` to recognise the TL directories. Nor do you need to modify `@INC` as the scripts do it themselves. `tlmgr` finds the paths and then arranges the directory order as necessary.

Nor should it be necessary to set any environmental variables such as `PERL5LIB`, although you do need to make sure that `perl` executables are in your `PATH`. For example, mine includes

```
... /usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl ...
```

But this will typically be ensured automatically by your Linux distribution when you install `perl`.

### Note 2

It is possible to configure things so logging in and out isn't necessary to switch between versions of TeX Live. For example, here's a selective listing of `/usr/local/texlive` on my machine

```sh
drwxr-xr-x  9 texlive texlive 4.0K Maw   3 02:37 2023/
drwxr-xr-x  9 texlive texlive 4.0K Maw  27 02:28 2024/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 texlive texlive    8 Maw  15 21:28 bin -> bin.2024/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 texlive texlive   21 Meh  17  2023 bin.2023 -> 2023/bin/x86_64-linux/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 texlive texlive   21 Maw  15 21:28 bin.2024 -> 2024/bin/x86_64-linux/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 texlive texlive   12 Maw  15 21:29 current -> current.2024/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 texlive texlive    4 Meh  17  2023 current.2023 -> 2023/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 texlive texlive    4 Maw  15 21:28 current.2024 -> 2024/
-rw-r--r--  1 texlive texlive 5.5M Meh  16  2023 install-tl-unx-2023.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 texlive texlive 5.6M Maw  15 19:25 install-tl-unx-2024.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 11 texlive texlive 4.0K Maw  27 02:28 texmf-local/
```

Then, instead of adding `/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/` to `PATH`, you add `/usr/local/texlive/bin/`. One additional advantage of this is that adding TeX Live to `PATH` is a one-time operation. You don't have to touch `PATH` when a new version of TeX Live is installed because `PATH` already points to the correct place once two symbolic links are adjusted.

This is inspired by the way MacTeX used to do it (and possibly still does) so that people could switch versions using a single click in a control pane. All that click did was adjust two symbolic links, just as demonstrated here.

[Actually, it was and is a bit more complicated on OS X because Apple, but those complications don't affect Linux, FreeBSD or similar.]